# Two way data binding with dynamic table and angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a table where I will have dynamic row creation. Everytime user clicks a button, a new row is created, as follows:

[image: angular]

The second column will contain the amount of products. So, I'd like to sum all values from second column to display them with two-way data binding, using bg-model and ng-bind. Thus when user types in one, the valus will automatically update. I have no clue about it, in that the rows are dynamic!

For a fixed number of elements it works, but I dunno for a dynamic generation. Help?

Comment: So are you asking for a function that can add up a dynamic list?

Comment: I'm asking for a way to add numbers in a dynamic list. These numbers should be added with ng-model in order to show users in real time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to initially setup an object to use and perhaps put in some example data

```
 $scope.ourTableArray = [];
 $scope.ourTableArray.push({'textColumn': 'example text', 'valueColumn': 10});
```

Because of the way that Angular works with data-binding we can bind the ng-repeat of the table row to an array that will contain all of our values:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in ourTableArray">
   <td><input type="text" ng-model="row.textColumn"</td>
   <td><input type="number" ng-model="row.valueColumn"</td>
</tr>
```

Next we need a way to add rows, so we can do that by creating a function to call on ng-click from some button. This will populate our `$scope.ourTableArray` following the format that was used in the first example value that we hardcoded in.

```
$scope.addRow = function(){
   $scope.ourTableArray.push({'textColumn': '', 'valueColumn': 0});
}
```

Now that the ng-repeat is set up we just need to have a way to calculate the values. The solution to that is by creating a function to sum up our `valueColumn` from our object:

```
$scope.calculateTotal = function() {
   var count = 0;
   for(row in $scope.ourTableArray){
      count += $scope.ourTableArray[row].valueColumn;
   }
   return count;
}
```

To output our new total all we have to do is call this function within our page.

```
Current Total of 2nd column: {{calculateTotal()}}
```

To summarize: Like I had stated above, because we have the ng-repeat binded to our array, anytime we modify the array (either by adding a row, removing a row, editing a rows values) it will be reflected immediately within the table.  In addition, since we are outputting the results of our `$calculateTotal()` function, anytime we modify one of the values within our array it will also change.

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/lliberacki/pen/mAdWBV)

Comment: If I tell you I did something similar and I though it didn't work because it was generating a weird number will you believe? The problem was that, the field was type 'text', and they were not being added, but concatenated. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, it definitely happens to the best of us sometimes, good'ol Javascript with it's typeless variables!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a table of objects with ID, name and value and a function that will add new data on scope to it. Then you in your controller you can add function that will simply sum all values and one that will edit object from table by ID.

Next as ng-repeat in this table display it in view. 
To all inputs in ng-repeat add function with sum and edit.

I did this in one of my projects but even if it works i don't think that's how it should be done. You can try it if you want.